# Выбор колонок в запросе SHOW TABLE STATUS

Tags: запрос, mysql

Мне нужно выбрать НЕ все колонки в запросе отображения статуса таблиц. Сейчас он выглядит так:

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS IN  `myTableName` WHERE  `NAME` LIKE  '%name_substring%';
```

Как его модифицировать, чтобы достичь желаемого эффекта и возможно ли это вообще?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте для получения нужной информации:

```
SELECT * 
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = 'db_name' AND table_name = 'table_name';
```

Здесь вы уже сможете указать только нужные столбцы.

Comment: маленькая ошибочка - 
не information_schema.table, а information_schema.tables
А так всё супер. Спасибо!